# Sendinblue create contact 'TypeError: Failed to fetch' error (using React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typeerror, sendinblue

I am trying to implement the Sendinblue API in my React JS application. I have a text input that the user is to enter their email into, and then a button that will add their email to a Sendinblue list. I am using the "Create a contact" reference located [here](https://developers.sendinblue.com/reference#createcontact) in Node.js, as I am using the JavaScript code for my React app. Sometimes, this code works, as the email is successfully added to the SendinBlue list, however most times the email is not added and I receive the following error:

`TypeError: Failed to fetch`

My full code can be seen below, where the email is input from the text field:

```
var request = require("request");

var options = {
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://api.sendinblue.com/v3/contacts',
  headers: {
    accept: 'application/json',
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'api-key': 'My SendinBlue Application API Key'
  },
  body: {updateEnabled: false, email: 'newEmail@exampleWebsite.com'},
  json: true
};

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);

  console.log(body);
});
```

When I test this on the Sendinblue API docs, it successfully adds the email to my contact list every time. I test it with a new email each time to ensure that it does not throw an error because of a duplicate email. I have also tinkered with the value of `updateEnabled` between `true` and `false` however it does not seem to help solve this issue.

I believe that the error may stem from the `var request = require("request");` command in the first line, as I am not sure if `require` is a React method or a Node.js method.

If anyone has any ideas on how I could fix this, your help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, `require` is used for Node.js and the example in the Sendinblue reference mentions it too. Try using `axios` instead. You just need to install it like any other npm module in your React project using `npm install axios` and try with the following script:

```
const response = await axios.post(
  'https://api.sendinblue.com/v3/contacts',
  { updateEnabled: false, email: 'newEmail@exampleWebsite.com'},
  { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'api-key': 'My SendinBlue Application API Key' } }
)
console.log(response.data)
```

Please let me know if it helps!
Thanks

Comment: Thank you for your response! When I run this new code, the email is added only occasionally, even after I added my correct api-key and I used a different email for each trial. It does not print anything in the console.log command (I even tried the alert command for this too), so I am not sure if this axios command is being run. Any ideas on why this may be?

Comment: You can try checking what does the `response` contain. It might be possible that the POST request failed and `response` object has the details about it.